# change the values and keys in two dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
MTgrades = { 18600028: 35, 18600041:98, 18701056: 80}
STNames={ "Kaplan":18600028, "Sherif":18600041,"Nshuti": 18701056}
```

How can I create a new dict (values from `MTgrades`, keys from `STNames`). I tried one but every name were paired with every grade. So Kaplan had 3, Sherif had 3, Nshuti had 3 grades. How can I fix it?

Comment: Show your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**
This should solve the issue.

```
{key:MTgrades[value] for key,value in STNames.items()}
```

Using comprehensive dictionary to create a new one, which keys are from `key` variable from STNames, and its value come from `MTgrades[value]` which map the values from STNames to values in MTgrades

```
MTgrades = { 18600028: 35, 18600041:98, 18701056: 80} 
STNames={ "Kaplan":18600028, "Sherif":18600041,"Nshuti": 18701056} 

print({key:MTgrades[value] for key,value in STNames.items()})
```

output:

```
{'Kaplan': 35, 'Sherif': 98, 'Nshuti': 80}
```

Comment: If I may suggest - `MTgrades.get(value)` instead of `MTgrades[value]`. Just in case a key is missing.